# UITableViewAutomaticDimension result in wrong Content View Hight

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have few custom cells (Subclass of `UITableViewCell`). Apparently when I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` the hight of Content View doesn't change to actual cell hight. I have read a few QA but non of them seems to solve my problem.

---

#### `viewDidLoad:`

Now everything works fine and the cells get different hight depending on the UITextView content.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Row Initial Settings
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 260

    //Register Cell
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
}
```

Now I want my custom cell **Content View** to also match the height of the cell.

---

#### `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

I know my subview constraint are correct cause if I use `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` everything fit in perfectly, but I don't want 1 cell hight, every cells have different setting.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //Fixed Cell Hight
    return 200
}
```

---

#### Screenshot of hirachy views.

[image]

How can i make this happen? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why would you return a fixed cell height when you're using `UITableViewAutomaticDimesion`? Just don't override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and let it calculates the height itself. And you don't need to set `self.tableView.rowHeight` two times like that.

Comment: Please read, I say  that was a test to see if constraint are correct. the problem here is Content View Hight, is not adjusting to cell hight when use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: then it should works well. What iOS version you're testing on?

Comment: iOS 9, I know its really weird. I even remove the bottom constraint of subview and add equal or greater height.

Comment: try remove `Container` and place all subview directly in `Content View`

Comment: @kientux It works. Wohoo Thanks mate. its always the small stuff :)

Comment: Nothing, glad it helps

Comment: if you want I will accept your answer if you write one.

Comment: Fine, maybe that's will help someone who has this problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your view hierarchy, your `Container` is not necessary. You should remove it and place all subviews directly in `Content View`.